# Python 3.3 C-API and UTF-8 Strings

Tags: python, c, unicode, python-c-api, python-internals

So, Python 3.3 introduced **[PEP 393](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/)**, which changes the implementation of Python `str` objects (Unicode objects) so that internally, they are represented in a memory-efficient way while still allowing for random access to each character.  This is done by scanning the string for the largest Unicode code point, and then choosing a Unicode encoding based on the size of the largest code point.  This way ASCII strings only require 1 byte per character, but strings with say, East Asian (Chinese/Japanese/Korean) code points will require 4 bytes per character.  This is much more efficient, memory-wise, than earlier implementations, which always used 2 or 4 bytes per character regardless of the actual code points in the string.

So I understand the purpose of **PEP 393**, but I'm really confused about how I'm supposed to go about creating a Python Unicode object from a UTF-8 encoded C string.  Creating a Python `str` from a UTF-8 C string is an *extremely common* requirement.  In fact, it's so common that the old (pre Python 3.3) C-API had a function entirely for that purpose:

```
PyObject* PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize(const char *u, Py_ssize_t size)
```

This function takes a UTF-8 C-string along with a size parameter, and creates a Python Unicode object from that string.

However, this function is now *deprecated* after PEP 393.  But I'm still not really sure exactly what is supposed to replace it.

At first I thought we could use the new `PyUnicode_FromKindAndData` function:

```
PyObject* PyUnicode_FromKindAndData(int kind, const void *buffer, Py_ssize_t size)
```

This new function takes a `"kind"` parameter, which indicates whether the input buffer is UCS1, UCS2, or UCS4.  Based on that parameter it creates a new compact Python Unicode object.  So, at first I thought that saying `PyUnicode_FromKindAndData(PyUnicode_1BYTE_KIND, buf, size)` would basically be equivalent to the old `PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize`.  I was thinking that `PyUnicode_1BYTE_KIND` means that Python should assume that the input buffer is a UTF-8 string.  But this doesn't seem to be the case.  UCS1 is not the same as UTF-8, and `PyUnicode_1BYTE_KIND` seems to just indicate that the input buffer has 1 byte per *character* - which is *not* the same as UTF-8, which is variable length and can have anywhere from 1 to 4 bytes per character.

So then, how can we create a Python Unicode object from a UTF-8 C string using the new PEP 393 API?

After reading [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_New) and PEP 393 itself, it seems to me that the only way to do this is to *manually compute* the maximum character yourself, and then call [**`PyUnicode_New`**](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_New).  Then iterate over the newly created string buffer, and *manually* convert each code point in the UTF-8 C string into the correct encoding based on the maxchar, copying each character using `PyUnicode_WRITE` in a loop.

... except I'm a bit surprised that the API would actually require all of this manual work - *including* all the conversions from UTF-8 to UTF-32 or UTF-16, taking into account things like surrogate pairs and all that.  Basically doing all these conversions manually is *a lot* of effort, and I'm surprised the Python C-API doesn't expose functions to do this in an easier way.  I mean, obviously such code exists in the Python source, since the old deprecated `PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize` was doing *exactly that*. It was converting UTF-8 to UTF-16 or UTF-32 (depending on the platform).  But now with PEP 393, it seems all of this has to be done manually.

So am I missing something?  Is there an easier way to create a Python Unicode object using a UTF-8 C string as input?  Or is it really necessary to do this all manually if we wish to avoid using the deprecated functions?

Comment: Isn't it just the `u = NULL` usage of `PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize` that's deprecated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PEP 393 does not specify any new API for converting from `UTF-*` encodings to Unicode. The old APIs still apply there.

If you do not need error handling, these 2 are still usable

```
PyObject* PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize(const char *u, Py_ssize_t size)
PyObject* PyUnicode_FromString(const char*u)
```

Only, `u` must not be NULL to the first one (it has been deprecated).

If you need error handling, or surrogate escapes, use [`PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#utf-8-codecs):

```
PyObject* PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8(const char *s, Py_ssize_t size, const char *errors)
```

These all use `PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8Stateful` internally. [`PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8Stateful`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5e44e8225938dfe64c93bdca27de424872aaed02/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L4841) now creates [new canonical `PyUnicodeObject`s](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5e44e8225938dfe64c93bdca27de424872aaed02/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L4878).

---

As for getting the UTF-8 representation of a `PyUnicodeObject` as `char *`, use either of

```
char* PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize(PyObject *unicode, Py_ssize_t *size)
char* PyUnicode_AsUTF8(PyObject *unicode)
```

This representation is cached in the `PyUnicodeObject` object itself and is valid for as long as that object itself is alive. These forms are especially useful if all the characters are ASCII, then the returned UTF-8 pointer can point just to the existing characters.

Comment: Does `PyUnicode_FromStringAndSize` and the old UTF-* API functions now create new "canonical" unicode objects - i.e. will these functions now automatically scan the input UTF-8 string to find the largest code point, and then use that to determine the minimum character size required?